# Meta Tags by Meta Box

Tags: customization, metabox

I have successfully added custom meta tags to metaboxes on my pages.  The issue I am having is when the metabox has no data it is still showing in the html.  This is the code I have got, does anyone have any ideas on how to not show this?

```
    <!-- Google Meta Tags -->
<meta name="citation_title" content="<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_title", true) !='' ) echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_title", true);?>">
<meta name="citation_author" content="<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_author", true) !='' ) echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_author", true);?>">
<meta name="citation_author" content="<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_author_1", true) !='' ) echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_author_1", true);?>">
<meta name="citation_author" content="<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_author_2", true) !='' ) echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_author_2", true);?>">
<meta name="citation_author" content="<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_author_3", true) !='' ) echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_author_3", true);?>">
<meta name="citation_author" content="<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_author_4", true) !='' ) echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_author_4", true);?>">
<meta name="citation_author" content="<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_author_5", true) !='' ) echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_author_5", true);?>">
<meta name="citation_author" content="<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_author_6", true) !='' ) echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_author_6", true);?>">
<meta name="citation_author" content="<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_author_7", true) !='' ) echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_author_7", true);?>">
<meta name="citation_author" content="<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_author_8", true) !='' ) echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_author_8", true);?>">
<meta name="citation_author" content="<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_author_9", true) !='' ) echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_author_9", true);?>">
<meta name="citation_publication_date" content="<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_publication_date", true) !='' ) echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_publication_date", true);?>">
<meta name="citation_journal_title" content="<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_journal_title", true) !='' ) echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_journal_title", true);?>">
<meta name="citation_volume" content="<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_volume", true) !='' ) echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_volume", true);?>">
<meta name="citation_issue" content="<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_issue", true) !='' ) echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_issue", true);?>">
<meta name="citation_firstpage" content="<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_first_page", true) !='' ) echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_first_page", true);?>">
<meta name="citation_lastpage" content="<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_last_page", true) !='' ) echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_last_page", true);?>">
<meta name="citation_pdf_url" content="<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_pdf_url", true) !='' ) echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_pdf_url", true);?>">
```

Comment: The metabox itself will show up if it is _registered_ regardless of content. That is how meta boxes work, and I am puzzled by the need to display a meta box only if it has content. How does the meta box get content in the first place if it only shows up after it has content?

Comment: I think I have the code wrong.  What I specifically need to is to output <meta name = "citation_title" content = "custom text"> into my header when there is data inputted into the metabox.  

I am going to try another way, but if someone has any ideas how to go about solving this it would be a great help! 

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is really just a PHP question, but since there is no Core function to do this...

I'd use `!empty()`. Otherwise just `echo` a string.

```
$mcontent = get_post_meta($post->ID, "vw_citation_title", true);
if(!empty($mcontent)) {
    echo '<meta name = "citation_title" content = "''.$mcontent.'" >';
}
```